# What is the difference between the properties "kernel_initializer" and "kernel" in layers.Dense?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/Dense?hl=en) on the TensorFlow website for `tf.layers.Dense`, it lists `kernel_initializer` and `kernel` as its properties. From what I understand, the `kernel_initializer` is an argument where you can pass the weight matrix. However, `kernel` also is a weight matrix.

What is the difference between these two and why would you pick one over the other when initializing the weights?

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can use `kernel_initializer` for *shortcut* initializations as zeros, ones, random_normal etc (you can see the full list [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/initializers)).

`kernel` will accept a set weight to be used as a kernel. While `kernel_initializer` will accept a [function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/initializers/Initializer) to be called by the framework to initialize the weight. The reason why these functions appear alike is that when you pass a matrix to kernel_initializer it is converted to a `constant` initiazlier which does exactly the same job as passing same matrix to the `kernel` parameter.